# Recursive XSLT transformation to simplify XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML:

```
<org.mule.module.json.JsonData>
  <node class="org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode">
    <__nodeFactory/>
    <__children>
      <entry>
        <string>freshdesk_webhook</string>
        <org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode>
          <__nodeFactory reference="../../../../__nodeFactory"/>
          <__children>
            <entry>
              <string>ticket_id</string>
              <org.codehaus.jackson.node.IntNode>
                <__value>7097</__value>
              </org.codehaus.jackson.node.IntNode>
            </entry>
            <entry>
              <string>ticket_requester_email</string>
              <org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode>
                <__value>walter@white.com</__value>
              </org.codehaus.jackson.node.TextNode>
            </entry>
          </__children>
        </org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode>
      </entry>
    </__children>
  </node>
</org.mule.module.json.JsonData>
```

And I need to transform it with XSLT to:

```
<root>
  <entry>
    <name>freshdesk_webhook</name>
    <value>
      <entry>
        <name>ticket_id</name>
        <value>7097</value>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <name>ticket_requester_email</name>
        <value>walter@white.com</value>
      </entry>
    </value>
  </entry>
</root>
```

Transformation is easy I believe. But I tested many XSLT today and have no result yet. How to get recursive XSLT to transform my heavy XML to my easy XML?

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly straightforward thanks to the fact that XSLT's [built in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) for elements simply keep processing children if there's no explicit match for a particular node, and the default rule for text nodes simply outputs the text.  So the mapping becomes

- top-level document element -> `root`
- `entry` -> `entry`
- first child element of each entry -> `name`
- second child element of each entry -> `value`

and for everything else just use the default "keep going with my children" rule

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <root><xsl:apply-templates /></root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <entry><xsl:apply-templates /></entry>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry/*[1]">
    <name><xsl:apply-templates /></name>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry/*[2]">
    <value><xsl:apply-templates /></value>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `xsl:strip-space` is important as that causes the stylesheet to ignore all the indentation in the input XML (the whitespace-only text nodes) and concentrate just on the elements and the significant text (the content of the `string` and `__value` elements).